# What are Carl Friedrich Gauss's contributions to acoustics?

Tags: physics

I read in many sites that Gauss worked in theoretical physics in the areas of mechanics, crystallography, acoustics, capillarity, electromagnetism and optics, but I couldn't find any place in his heritage in which he made contributions to acoustics. I'm very interested to learn of his contributions in this field.

Comment: This seems to be from [Quora](http://www.quora.com/What-are-carl-friedrich-gausss-contributions-to-acoustics?share=1). Also, do you have anything to suggest that he made any contributions to the field? On another note, [Gauss's law can be used in acoustics](http://arxiv.org/abs/1104.0893).

Comment: In Gauss's biography - Gauss: A Biographical study, there is a bibliography of his publications and one of them (published posthumously) is titled "acoustics".

Comment: Some simple googling yields several applications of Gauss' work to acoustics. Could you make your question more specific? What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I look for direct application made by gauss of mathematics to acoustical problems: for example how the different shapes of concert halls affects their acoustical properties? Something that takes into acount the infinite number of reflections of sound waves from the walls. Gauss directly refered to acoustics (in a letter to weber) as "a field which still the most brilliant advances are to be made". So i look for direct treatment of acoustical problems, not an apllication of some of his mathematical ideas to acoustics.